# How to identify the window is belong to a specific process?

Tags: windows, winapi

Win32 programs have an entry parameter `HINSTANCE` for the Win32 entry function `WinMain()`. When you create your own window, the `CreateWindow()` API call needs this parameter.

My first idea in my mind is that this `HINSTANCE` should be some unique identify to distinguish different windows belong to different processes. Until recently, in some occasions, I use this `HINSTANCE`. Wow! If you open the same Win32 program (EXE) twice, each process has **the same** `HINSTANCE` value.

Later I figured out, it was some resource identifier (memory address) in the process. It's a virtual address for the process which is related to its PE structure in memory.

Now, if I have the two windows' `HWND` handles, and I want to check whether the two windows are from the same process, what is the best choice?

Comment: [What is the HINSTANCE passed to CreateWindow and RegisterClass used for?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050418-59/?p=35873)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`GetWindowThreadProcessId` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) to retrieve the ID of the process that created a window, given that window's `HWND`.

Below is a brief C code snippet showing how. We check that the return value of each `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` call is not zero ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5828081/10871073) or [this blog by Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040223-00/?p=40503)), to ensure that we have passed valid `HWND` handles.

```c
// win1 and win2 are both HWND handles to check...
DWORD proc1, proc2;

if (!GetWindowThreadProcessId(win1, &proc1)) { // Error (invalid HWND?)
    //.. error handling
}
if (!GetWindowThreadProcessId(win2, &proc2)) {
    //..
}

if (proc1 == proc2) {
    // Windows created by same process
}
else {
    // Windows created by different processes
}
```

Comment: "*You can ignore the return value*" - you shouldn't ignore it. At the very least, check it to make sure the function doesn't fail, ie if the HWNDs are no longer valid.

Comment: @Remy OK, code modified according to the info provided in Raymond's blog and in the linked SO answer.

Answer (score 0):

`GetWindowThreadProcessId` can do the work. Record here.

Answer (score 0):

An interactive way to do this would be to use Microsoft's [Spy++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2019), which lets you find the Process ID, Thread ID, and parents/children of a window by point-and-clicking its GUI.

You can also find window handles (and plenty of other window-specific data) in this way.